# Adoptability of token program 2022

Tags: program, token

So I'm having to create a nontransferable spl token and token program 2022 does provide features for it. The thing is I want to know that has the program been globally accepted in the solana ecosystem so that if I create a token it would be recognized as a valid spl token and not an arbitrary account on the sol Blockchain ecosystem.

Answer (score 3):

The Token 2022 program is currently supported in major wallets like Solflare, Phantom, and Backpack in the sense that it shows the balance and icon, etc. They might not implement all extensions though.

In the official Solana Explorer, the tokens created with the Token 2022 don't show up yet at the time of writing though I can imagine this will be added soon as the program will be officially [launched alongside 1.17 adoption on mainnet](https://twitter.com/Austin_Federa/status/1742248253612011959) under the 'Token Extensions' name.

I'd say Token 2022 is probably a safe bet to start using it today if you want to use one of its extensions.